# how jvm load different jars but same package name and class name?

Tags: java, jvm

> i am puzzled about two same class in different jars ,but project show different behaviors . such as below :

**jar: test1.jar  class : cn.oom.test.HelloTests**

```java
  public class HelloTests {
   /**
    * greet
    *
    * @return
    */
   public static String greet(String greet) {
       System.out.println("test1 " + greet);
       return "test1" + greet;
   }
}
```

**jar: test2.jar  class : cn.oom.test.HelloTests**

```java
 public class HelloTests {
   /**
    * greet
    *
    * @return
    */
   public static String greet(String greet) {
       System.out.println("test2 " + greet);
       return "test2" + greet;
   }
}
```

> in my project(a springboot project) : atest ,i add dependency like

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>cn.oom.test1</groupId>
            <artifactId>test1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cn.oom.test2</groupId>
            <artifactId>test2</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
```

then test the class like

```java
@Component
public class ATests implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        HelloTests.greet("hello");
        //
    }
}
```

it shows:

> test1 hello

when swith the dependency import like

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>cn.oom.test2</groupId>
            <artifactId>test2</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cn.oom.test1</groupId>
            <artifactId>test1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
```

the same code shows :

> test2 hello

what i am *puzzled* is : when i package the project as a jar file ,use `java -jar atest.jar`
the project always show

> test2 hello

---

- why is this result?
- is not jvm load jars from classpath order by file name ?
- why does the jar project show same as the dependency import sequence?(when pom 
  first import test1,the jar print test1, when pom first import test2, the jar pirint test2 ) ?

Comment: What do you think, is your actual classpath?

Comment: i am confused about this ,two jars in classpath of the project jar file(my: atest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar\BOOT-INF\lib\test1.jar [test2.jar]) , why print different result ? 
this seems has relation with the  pom dependency sequence . but when package to a jar file ,why is it still has relation ?

Comment: The builtin class loader does not support loading classes from jar files contained in jar files. So there’s some other software involved. Software, which is configured by your springboot configuration. It should not come as a surprise that it will ensure the behavior. The actual question is, why do you expect a different behavior?